# get id of an item in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have this in my values xml file:

```
<string-array name="ben_country_list">
    <item id="103">India</item>
    <item id="210">Sri Lanka</item>
    <item id="235">United Kingdom</item>
    <item id="76">France</item>
    <item id="216">Switzerland</item>
    <item id="200">Singapore</item>
    <item id="234">United Arab Emirates</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to get country's ID. I tried with below code:

```
final Spinner mBenCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
mBenCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        final long ben_country = mBenCountry.getSelectedItemPosition();
        final long ben_country2 = parentView.getSelectedItemId();
        System.out.println(ben_country); // This one gives me position like 0,1,2...
        System.out.println(ben_country2); // Output: same as above...
    }
});
```

I want to get actual IDs of the selected item. For example, if user selects united kingdom then it should print `235`. I **don't want** name of that item.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate integer-array in XML for the ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <integer-array name="ben_country_ids">
          <item>103</item>
          <item>210</item>
          <item>235</item>
          <item>76</item>
          <item>216</item>
          <item>200</item>
          <item>234</item>
     </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Get the int array in code:

```
final int[] benCountryIds = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ben_country_ids);
```

Using the `position` get the correct id from the array in `onItemSelected`:

```
int countryId = benCountryIds[position];
```

Comment: I know, what you are trying to say. But, this way is not maintainable.

Comment: Please explain why you think it is not maintainable.

Comment: If I will change the country list then, I also need to change this integer array. and I also need to take care of the sequence of the list. But, I think it's according to @Robertas Setkus's answer, there is no such a option to do it the way I mentioned.

Comment: Yep, you will have to use two arrays.

Comment: This is the only way. And yes, you'll have to add / remove in both array items. Can't see why that's a problem ?
If you need dynamic interaction, Spinner might not be your best choice for it.

Comment: @AndroidNFC : What should I use to achieve dynamic interaction other than spinner?

Comment: Hm. What first comes to mind..ListView ? But I understand that it's quite completely different UI than Spinner, but I know that you can items to list dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the selected item position, you can do this:

```
mBenCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

        switch (id) {
            case 103 : 
                System.out.println("India");
                break;
            case 210:
                System.out.println("Sri Lanka");
                break;
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: I think that id is the view's id and not the id he is looking for.

Comment: I don't want country names. I just want it's `id` that I am passing in xml.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, android [string-array XML structure](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) doesn't support key/value pairs for item entries. So, you have to use other data source etc.: database table, CSV file or whatever else. Then load data into some collection and then pass it to custom adapter.